# Wordpress NetworkError 403/404 : for /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php on this server

Tags: ajax, wordpress

`admin-ajax.php` file not found in registration using userpro plugin.

i check field validation using `admin-ajax.php` its workind  but click on register button using `admin-ajax.php` its not working

```
 NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

Comment: Are you working with HTTPS? I had some problems accessing `admin-ajax.php` when I worked in a HTTPS project

Comment: no i work in http://

Comment: Ok, then show some more code. How is the JS calling the ajax? Have you correctly added the `wp_ajax_*` and [`wp_ajax_nopriv_*`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_%28action%29) hooks?